# Vertical alignment of a div using Semantic-UI

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I can't seem to find it anywhere in the docs.

Is there a way to vertically center a div on the page using Semantic-UI semantics :)

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
<div class="ui centered grid">
  <div class="eight column wide">
    <div>I want to be centered vertically on a page</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually went ahead and implemented it ["manully"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

http://semantic-ui.com/examples/grid.html

Use `middle aligned` class on `grid`

Comment: Note: If there is a `ui container` tag before the `ui grid` `middle aligned` don't works properly, remove ui container and it's going to work, thanx.

Answer (score 8):

This issue was reported [HERE](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/6077) early 2018 but closed.

However, you can try this :

```
<div id="my-container" class="ui grid middle aligned">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="ui text container segment inverted">
        <h1>My DIV</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make sure your container is tall enough

```
#my-container {
  background: #000;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Try it on JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Peyothe/6rjmdu1x/

Comment: Thanks class="ui grid centered middle aligned" worked for me

Answer (score 5):

I just achieved this by using `middle` and setting heights to certain elements:

```css
.holder {
  height: 400px
}
.holder .middle {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/master/dist/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="holder">
  <div class="ui middle aligned grid">
    <div class="eight column wide">
      <div>I want to be centered vertically on a page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I don't know if it used to but if you run the snippet, you will see that the text is not vertically centered.